# Linux packet routing

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iproute

I'd like to route traffic from one Ethernet to another only if a given rule is met.
The "rule" is as follows : if a specif value (numeric or string) is found within the packet - the traffic is forwarded, otherwise - discard it. 
The "rule" should be able to search from a given offset. ( Packet inspection )

Can this be achieved using Linux Standard tools ? ( iproute2\ethtool\ etc' ) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I advise writing concise questions. It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Something akin to IPS?

Comment: Note that this will only affect single packets, and not the complete stream. In case this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please describe the X. For example, if X is "I want to handle certain web pages in a special way", consider a transparent proxy. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with the module `string`.

`man iptables-extensions`:

> The string pattern can be used for simple text characters.
>    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --algo bm --string 'GET /index.html' -j LOG
>
> The hex string pattern can be used for non-printable characters, like |0D 0A| or |0D0A|.
>    iptables -p udp --dport 53 -m string --algo bm --from 40 --to 57 --hex-string '|03|www|09|netfilter|03|org|00|'

Comment: Thanks can iptables rules be "or'd" \ "and" ?

Comment: @user3087632 All tests within the same `iptables` call are ANDed. For OR you need several rules.